# TFS API find Area Path by Team Name

Tags: tfs

In my organization the TFS is setup with project and project is set with teams and teams have iterations

Team Project
 - Team 1
  - Iteration
 - Team 2
  - Iteration 1
  - Iteration 2

How can I find Area Path and Iteration by Team Name programatically using TFS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify the team name in [Team field values](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/team-field-values) Rest API.

> The team field is used to identify which work items belong to your
>   team. By default, **Area Path** is the team field, but it can be any
>   field. Use this API to get and set the the team field values.

Sample: **Get a team field values**

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/Work/TeamSettings/TeamFieldValues?api-version={version}
```

Will return including three area paths:

Default is `Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto` and `"Fabrikam-Fiber\\Fiber"` and  `"Fabrikam-Fiber\\Optics"`

```
"field": {
    "referenceName": "System.AreaPath",
    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.AreaPath"
  },
  "defaultValue": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Auto",
      "includeChildren": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Fiber",
      "includeChildren": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber\\Optics",
      "includeChildren": false
    }
```